# Tab Widget having a horizontal black line in the background in ICS

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I am facing a strange problem with tabs when using ICS. There is a horizontal black line in the background running from left to right in the tabwidget. It shows up in the divider between tabs (as shown in the image attached)

[image: tab bar in Ice Cream Sandwitch**strong text**]

Comment: Found the answer...It was due to using TabActivity which is deprecated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer...It was due to using TabActivity which is deprecated now